# How do I move a MySQL database from one hard drive to another?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL 5.5 and MySQLWorkbench on Windows7. I have successfully created a database on my C: drive but I want to move it to my E: drive. I stopped the mysqld daemon and edited the my.ini file to change datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/" to datadir="E:/MySQL/data/". I copied the data from the C: location to the E: location.
I can start the mysqld process, but the database I created does not appear. Would anyone have any explanation as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where was the `my.ini` file that you changed?  Could it still be pointing back to the `C:` location?

Comment: Its pointing to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

As I wanted my innodb database to sit on another partition, I stopped MySQL from the MySQL Workbench. I copied my innodb database ibdata1 as well as 2 log files which MySQL automatically created in my C:\ProgramData\MySQL\ folder to a new folder on my E: partition. I added the following to my.ini:

```
innodb_data_home_dir = "E:/MySQL Data"
```

Now, when I start my database, all changes are made to the ibdata1 in the E: drive.

Comment: See the following [innodb-configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you would like to copy all the contents in the old directory to the new directory. Make sure that while doing this you don't also copy binlogs (if any, they look like mysql-bin.001 etc. and also don't copy mysql-bin.index because that contains real path reference to the old binary logs). Once you do that, you should be able to restart the mysql daemon and login to see the databases.

PS: not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to move my database I ran into the issue where windows didn't have the same permissions on the new data folder as the original. You may check that the correct user(s) have access to the new folder by going to the properties of the folder then selecting the security tab.

Answer (score -1):

Dump your database to disk using this tool http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlbutool/ Then restore it to the new server using this tool http://www.webyog.com/

Comment: I'm not moving it to another server. I want the actual data to be sourced from the E: drive and not the C: drive. I want mySQL to live on the C: drive.

Comment: Right now, my innodb data is stored in a hidden folder on the server: C:\Program Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\ which I want to move to the E: drive

Comment: Can I copy the data in my current innodb_data_home_dir to a new location and then specify the new location as the proper innodb_data_home_dir path?